# gcloud storage cp not preserving directory structure when copy cloud to cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-cloud-data-transfer

I am trying to copy all the data from source bucket to destination bucket using below command recursively

```
gcloud storage cp -r "gs://test-1" "gs://test-3" --encryption-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --manifest-path=test-manifest.csv --storage-class=REGIONAL
```

Logs from above command

```
Copying gs://test-1/abcd/efgh/jklm to gs://test-3/test-1/abcd/efgh/jklm
```

However `test-1` is getting copied into `test-3` bucket as a directory.

I want to keep `test-1` structure same as `test-3` like.

```
Copying gs://test-1/abcd/efgh/jklm to gs://test-3/abcd/efgh/jklm
```

I tried gsutil cp as well but it gave me same issue.

rsync command is not working at all and exiting.

How can i preserve the structure while copying ?

Answer (score 3):

### Using Wildcards

It is possible to preserve the directory structure with the help of wildcards.

```
gcloud storage cp -r "gs://test-1/*" "gs://test-3" --encryption-key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Reference :

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/wildcards#surprising-behavior